# How to handle multiple middlewares in NEST JS for specific/different request methods?

Tags: node.js, middleware, nestjs, nestjs-config

> **Explaining my code below:** There are two middleware AuthenticationMiddleware, RequestFilterMiddleware which intervene ALL request methods.

**My question** is how to make `RequestFilterMiddleware` middleware only for GET method and `AuthenticationMiddleware` middleware for ALL request methods

**app.module.ts**

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(AuthenticationMiddleware, RequestFilterMiddleware)
      .forRoutes({ path: '/**', method: RequestMethod.ALL });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That should do it, no?

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(AuthenticationMiddleware)
      .forRoutes({ path: '/**', method: RequestMethod.ALL });
    consumer
      .apply(RequestFilterMiddleware)
      .forRoutes({ path: '/**', method: RequestMethod.GET });
  }
}
```